# How to create a "Go to your mailbox" button

Tags: javascript, forms, email

I want to create a button that will appear after the user have entered successfully his email address to register. The button will say: "Go to your mailbox". This button would take the user to the email client entered in the domain name of the email address entered.

For example if user registered with email address: someone@yahoo.com, the button opens yahoo mail. But if the user registered with gmail.com, the button opens gmail when clicked.

Comment: How about you just substring from `@` sign to the end and then you have to either open that domain or parse the domain further and manually redirect given your results.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make sure to give a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var valid_email_check = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}))$/ ;
var email = "youremail@domain.com";
if(valid_email_check.test(email)){
  var mail_domain = email.split('@');
  var link  = mail_domain[1];
  _your button holder_.html('<a href="'+ link +'"><button type="button">Go to your mailbox</button></a>');
}
```

hope this will answer your answer..